# Font Color Isn't Changing

Tags: html, css

I know this is a rookie question, but why isn't my font colour changing?

My HTML:

```
<h1 class="InternetTitle">Internet Services</h1>
```

My CSS:

```
.InternetTitle {
  color: 2777fd;
  text-align: center;
}
```

It aligns my text vertically, but it doesn't change my color.  And I can't figure out why.

I've also tried:

```
<h1>Internet Services</h1>

h1 {
  color: 2777fd;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/css/644/colors/2100/hexadecimal-value#t=201607221910443786012

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're missing the # - `color: #2777fd`.

Comment: ... wow....

That's embarrassing.

Comment: I'll accept your answer when I can.

Comment: Next time, use Google Chrome's inspect feature as a debugger. It's very useful for making quick changes and seeing real time updates to the design.

Comment: It would have shown a line through that property so you would know it wasn't applying.

Comment: I'm chalking this one up to "Friday afternoon troubleshooting goggles" myself..

Comment: 11 upvotes? You people are feeling generous today.

Comment: @Toby I hope you're right... we converted this site from Wix so I have walls of HTML text to go through.  Now I've got a pounding headache, and I've just made this embarrassment of a mistake.

Oh well, c'est la vie.